# Pass id from redux into state of component

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

Here is state of my component:

```
 state = {
          data: {
            userId: `${user.id}`,
            name: '',
            country: '',
            city: ''
        },
        loading: false,
        errors: {}
       };
```

And using redux I retrieve the user id from logged in user:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    user: state.user
  }
}
QuestForm.propTypes = {
  user:PropTypes.shape({
    email: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }).isRequired,
  submit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Form);
```

It complains to me that `'user' is not defined  no-undef`

Is there a problem with syntax within a state or with my redux logic approach?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you have a codepen or something?

Comment: its not possible to answer that clearly. e.g. your state snippet.. where does the user variable come from? your component source is incomplete. its also not totally clear if your state snippet is a component state or the redux state.  since u wrote `state of my component` i assume component state. also its an antipattern to set a state dependent to your props.

Comment: Can you post the code for your component, where state is defined?

Comment: @JuHwon, I wanted to pass the user from redux to the state of a component. This component is not for the user, but for the game. The only reason I do that is to save after in API call that this game was created by this particular user. I did not find another way to pass userId as a param in api call except passing id as a part of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${user.id}` should be `${props.user.id}` or `${this.props.user.id}` depending whether you have a class or function based component.

`user` is not defined because that's not how you access props :)

Comment: `${this.props.user.id}` is working. But I am not sure I understand why. Because in my logic, I was calling `user` from `function mapStateToProps(state)`, thinking that I can get any element from redux store in this way. now it appears, that there is no need for redux in order to get a user. as your solution means I am getting just using simple react. Am I right?

Comment: the name `mapStateToProps` actually tells you what happens, it gets whatever you return from that function an passes it as `props`, in your case it returns the object with the property `user`, which then becomes available on props, and the way to access props is by using `this.props` and the property name that you return from `mapStateToProps` on class bases components.